# R applying function to multiple data frames

Tags: r

I have three dataframes that each have a `rn_description` column and a `label` column. For each dataframe, I want to read the text in the `description` column, and depending if `grepl` finds certain strings, I want to label the `label` column appropriately.

I've tried

```
l=list(df1_wlabel= df1_wlabel,df2_wlabel=df2_wlabel,df3_wlabel=df3_wlabel)


l <- lapply(l , 
            function(df){
  
                df$label <- ifelse(grepl("email|e-mail", df$rn_description), "email", df$label)
                df$label <- ifelse(grepl("phone|call|voicemail|conversation|convo", 
                             df$rn_description), "phone", df$label)
                df$label <- ifelse(grepl("text", df$rn_description), "text", df$label)
                return(df)
             }     
     )
```

I've also tried a for loop

```
for (i in 1:length(l)){    
                l[i]$label <- ifelse(grepl("email|e-mail", l[i]$rn_description), "email", l[i]$label)
                l[i]$label <- ifelse(grepl("phone|call|voicemail|conversation|convo", 
                               l[i]$rn_description), "phone", l[i]$label)
                l[i]$label <- ifelse(grepl("text", l[i]$rn_description), "text", l[i]$label)
}
```

But none of these ways properly changes the `label` column. Only explicitly writing out the changes for each dataframe works like so:

```
df1_wlabel$label <- ifelse(grepl("email|e-mail", df1_wlabel$rn_description), "email", df1_wlabel$label)
df1_wlabel$label <- ifelse(grepl("phone|call|voicemail|conversation|convo", df1_wlabel$rn_description), "phone", df1_wlabel$label)

df1_wlabel$label <- ifelse(grepl("text", df1_wlabel$rn_description), "text", df1_wlabel$label)
#then do this again for each dataframe
```

Why do the first two ways not work, but the last way works?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. After the code runs, are you checking the values in the list `l`? Because that's what your code is updating. You are creating (lazy) copies of the data.frames when you create the list.

Comment: I didn't realize that only the dataframes in the list get updated - indeed, upon checking list `l` the dataframes in there are indeed updated. Is there any way to implement the code so that the original ones get updated as well?

Comment: A better thing to fix would be the part where you created a bunch of data frames with indexes in their names. If you have related data, you should start with them in a list in the first place. Variables with numbers in their names is usually a bad R code smell.  See this answer in particular: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/2372064